# Does a snap for vscode exist?

Tags: snap, visual-studio-code

The media is gushing about the snap package for Visual Studio Code, and how wonderful it is (apparently has a plug in that cures gout ;-). So I thought I'd give it a whirl. I dutifully typed:

```
$ sudo snap install --classic vscode
error: cannot install "vscode": snap not found
```

Where the articles all too early? Has vscode not yet landed in snap?

Comment: A link to said article would suffice!

Comment: What vesion of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: The snap is only available for amd64. Are you running on a different architecture? You can run the `arch` command in a terminal to find out.

Comment: @George http://news.softpedia.com/news/you-can-now-install-microsoft-s-visual-studio-code-ide-as-a-snap-on-ubuntu-linux-515882.shtml

Comment: Evan, that is probably the issue. I'm running on a fairly old Intel based system. It would have been really helpful if the articles mentioned that rather important restriction.

Comment: Please output the `$ snap find "visual studio code"` in your question above it will help resolve the issue and you may alos try to invert --classic position at the end of command.

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio Code should show up in Ubuntu Software application if you search for "vscode" or it can be installed from the terminal by running the command `sudo snap install code --classic` A snap in classic confinement behaves as a traditionally packaged application with full access to the system, and Visual Studio Code extensions are installed into the user's home directory.

Visual Studio Code is not an full=featured IDE. For this reason it is not possible to create a project in Visual Studio Code, like it is in Visual Studio. On the other hand it is possible to run Python, C, C++, JavaScript, PHP, Java, R and some other programming language code blocks directly in Visual Studio Code using the Code Runner extension. It is also possible to run HTML code in an external web browser using the open in browser extension. Visual Studio Code is a lot smaller than Microsoft Visual Studio, however many Visual Studio extensions can also be installed in Visual Studio Code by selecting *View* -> *Extensions* and then search for the extension that you want to install.

Comment: apt and snap are completely separate. `sudo apt update` will not have an effect on snap packages and there's no need for an equivalent of it for snaps.

When you run `snap install --classic vscode` it checks the snap store to see if vscode exists, then installs it.

Comment: I did `sudo snap install vscode --classic` and see it in `snap list`. However, I cannot start it with `code` or `snap run code` The publisher is snapcrafters. Is this broken for Ubuntu 20_04? Code-insiders works.

Comment: I'm using code-insiders in Ubuntu 20.04 because one of my Visual Studio Code extensions is not supported by code.

Answer (score 2):

I just searched and got this result:

1. Find it:

   ```
   snap find vscode

   Name    Version            Developer      Notes    Summary
   vscode  1.12.2-1494422229  flexiondotorg  classic  Code editing. Redefined.
   ```
2. Install it:

   ```
   sudo snap install --classic vscode
   ```
3. Results:

   ```
   [sudo] password for george: 
   core 71.70 MB / 79.49 MB 
   [==============================================================>------]  90.21% 527.42 KB/s 15svscode 1.12.2-1494422229 from 'flexiondotorg' installed
   ```