# How to launch the vscode after it has been installed through snap?

Tags: snap

run the command as below:

```
sudo snap install --classic vscode
```

I install the vscode successfully. But I can not launch the vscode.

Comment: What Linux distribution and version are you using? What is the output of ```snap version```?

Comment: I can find the vscode after restart the computer.

Comment: @wlos Thanks. I had this exact same problem. I did not have to restart. I could simply logout and log back in.

Answer (score 6):

If

```
code
```

doesn't work try

```
snap run code
```

Answer (score 2):

I installed vscode with the same command, and it launched when I clicked on the Visual Studio Code icon in the Dash.

There are now two Visual Studio Code snap packages in Ubuntu: *code* and *code-insiders*. code-insiders is the newer snap package that was packaged by Microsoft. To start these packages from the terminal type:

```
snap run code-insiders
```

or

```
snap run code
```

For more information read my [other answer about installing Visual Studio Code](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917281/snap-for-vscode-does-not-exist/917290#917290).

Comment: I have found the vscode in Dash.

Comment: What happens when you try to launch it from the terminal with the command `vscode` ?

Comment: It shows "command not found". But now I can launch the vscode through Dash or terminal after restarting my computer.

Comment: When I installed vscode on my computer it launched immediately by clicking on the icon, but I guess it's alright now. Watch out when installing debugging extensions. They try to turn your Ubuntu into Windows and then they don't work anyway.

Comment: I am in the VScode terminal and want to open a file from there, like "code file1". "Code" is not recognized, this is a path issue to solve. "snap run code" opens a new VSCode instance which I do not want. Similar action would be "ctrl+1"/go to editor and "ctrl+o", which is my current procedure. . In windows "code" from the terminal  works, but not in Ubuntu.

Comment: I got the solution to my observation from some minutes before, in preferences: `"window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off"`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the executable name is "code".
So, all you need to do is enter:

```
   code
```

If you navigate to a project folder and do:

```
   code .
```

Then, it will open that folder as a "project".