# Visual Studio code not installing in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-center, visual-studio-code

I have downloaded Visual Studio from [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) link. When I try to install it is not installing.

I tried to install in software center but it is not installing.

I tried with `umake web visual-studio-code` command but it throws warning `WARNING: Visual Studio Code is now in the ide category, please refer it from this category from now on. This compatibility will be dropped after Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Choose installation path: /home/ufff/.local/share/umake/web/visual-studio-cod`

At last it throws this error and is not installed:

```
Current thread 0x00007fb9b29f6700 (most recent call first):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py", line 573 in run
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/tools.py", line 139 in run
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/__init__.py", line 131 in main
File "/usr/bin/umake", line 9 in <module>
```

[image]

I have tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917281/snap-for-vscode-does-not-exist) answer also but it throws the 404 error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [snap for vscode does not exist?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917281/snap-for-vscode-does-not-exist)

Comment: The link you posted seems to be a documentation page - did you download it from the [downloads page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download), the `.deb` version ?

Comment: Yes I download from that link only