# Visual Studio Code wont launch after installing

Tags: permissions, 18.04, visual-studio-code

**>NOT ABOUT SNAP VERSION<**

Installed Visual Studio Code via terminal using the instructions here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

I didn't do the `sudo dpkg -i <file>.deb` and `sudo apt-get install -f` but went right to adding repository and key, followed by updating and installing (`sudo apt install code`).

When starting it the normal way (<kbd>**Super**</kbd> and typing `visual`, enter to start the app) shows the busy-cursor for a while and then stops. Nothing happens.

When starting using the terminal, typing `code`, nothing happens.

```
$ code --verbose

[main 9:06:54 PM] Startup error: ,,Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/*myusername*/.config/Code/CachedData',Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/*myusername*/.config/Code/logs/20180723T210654'
[main 9:06:54 PM] Lifecycle#kill()

$ apt list --installed code

Listing... Done
code/stable,now 1.25.1-1531323788 amd64 [installed]
N: There are 39 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.

$ apt policy code

code:
  Installed: 1.25.1-1531323788
  Candidate: 1.25.1-1531323788
  Version table:
 *** 1.25.1-1531323788 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.25.0-1530796411 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.24.1-1528912196 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.24.0-1528306776 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.23.1-1525968403 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.23.0-1525361119 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.22.2-1523551015 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.22.1-1522974421 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.21.1-1521038896 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.21.0-1520420608 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.20.1-1518535978 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.20.0-1518023506 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.19.3-1516876437 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.19.2-1515599945 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.19.1-1513676564 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.19.0-1513245498 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.18.1-1510857349 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.18.0-1510145176 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.17.2-1508162334 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.17.1-1507645403 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.17.0-1507160143 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.16.1-1505406497 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.16.0-1504714880 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.15.1-1502903936 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.15.0-1502309460 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.14.2-1500506907 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.14.1-1499973263 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.14.0-1499719149 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.13.1-1497464373 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.13.0-1496940180 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.12.2-1494422229 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.12.1-1493934083 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.12.0-1493915672 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.11.2-1492070517 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.11.1-1491486998 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.11.0-1491426847 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.10.2-1488981323 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.10.1-1488415350 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.10.0-1488387854 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.9.1-1486597190 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
```

As for the rights on the .config dir:

```
$ ls -la ~/.config/Code

total 24
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root   4096 jun 25 23:08 .
drwx------ 19 myusername myusername 4096 jun 29 18:59 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     18 jun 25 23:08 installSource
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root   4096 jun 25 23:08 logs
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     36 jun 25 23:08 machineid
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   4096 jun 25 23:08 User
```

I'm pretty new. Apparently "sudo code" is not a safe way to solve my problem so what should I do?

Running Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: How did you install visual code ? On this page several methods are mentioned! Did you get installation errors? What is the output of `apt policy code`and what shows `apt list --installed code` . **Put the output of this commands into your original post**

Comment: Thanks for your reply @abu_bua! I just clarified which instructions I used. I will add the output later today when I have access to my system again.

Comment: @abu_bua I added the output. Hope that makes things clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @karel. I prefer to avoid a snap version of it, for now, though. :)

Comment: Seems you don't have write access in the config dir. What does the command `ls -la ~/config/Code`outputs ?

Comment: @abu_bua, I added the output. That indicates that I do have write permission, right?

Comment: No. First the apt policy seems to be right. For some reason however the right permissions are set wrong, see my answer above. I have installed Code for x-times, and it is strange that you root permissions in your config file. Maybe it results from a former wrong installation.

Comment: @Thomas No, I already mentioned above that this is not about a snap version. Thanks, though. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a snap for vscode exist?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917281/does-a-snap-for-vscode-exist)

Comment: @N0rbert It isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the permission! The settings are wrong. If you have a **new** installation and never had projects on your machine, try to reinstall code, by deleting all code-made-files

```
sudo apt purge code
```

and then reinstall it with

```
sudo apt install code
```

If you have had projects, you may try to change your access of the config dir:

```
sudo chown -R myusername:myusername ~/.config/Code
```