# Problem installing Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 18.04.1 (not found libgconf-2-4)

Tags: 18.04, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to install VS Code into a Ubuntu 18.04.1 but system can't found libgconf-2-4.

```
> sudo dpkg -i code_1.25.1-1531323788_amd64.deb 

Selecting previously unselected package code.
(Reading database ... 146489 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack code_1.25.1-1531323788_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking code (1.25.1-1531323788) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of code:
 code depends on libgconf-2-4; however:
  Package libgconf-2-4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package code (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 code
```

I tried installing the library libgconf-2-4 manually but it have more dependencies and I don't want to be that cyclically.

Are there a way to install it *easier*?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a snap for vscode exist?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917281/does-a-snap-for-vscode-exist)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f` will fix problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `gdebi` instead of `dpkg` to install "out of distro" deb files. `gdebi` will install the dependencies of the `deb` (provided they are in the Ubuntu repositories), and then the deb.

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
sudo gdebi code_*.deb
```

Answer (score 4):

I met with the same problem. Try the following commands.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo dpkg -i code_*.deb
```

It works for me. Hope it helps you.