# WPF programming on Unix with C#

Tags: c#

I am a wanna-be programmer aka computer science student and I have a lecture in C#. But I only have a Mac and a Linux computer.

I need to be able to program an app with interface and logic (XAML/C#). And I don't know how I can do that on Linux. Please help me! I don't have Windows on any computer. I know that I can program the "backend" in C# on Linux but I can't use the visual tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Avalonia](https://avaloniaui.net/) is an open source cross-platform XAML Framework for .NET Framework, .NET Core and Mono.

Avalonia uses a XAML dialect that should feel immediately familiar to anyone coming from WPF, UWP and Xamarin Forms. Avalonia supports binding, MVVM, lookless controls and data templates, just as you'd expect from a XAML framework.

[XML Complete](https://github.com/rogalmic/vscode-xml-complete) extension for [Visual Studio Code](https://askubuntu.com/a/917290/) helps with editing XML files by providing hints. Sample schema files are provided for XAML file types (WPF, Avalonia) and for csproj files.

Visual Studio Code is much less full-featured than Visual Studio, but it has the capability of running GUI applications. If that's not enough functionality for your coursework try [Visual Studio 2019 for Mac](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/). Be aware before you install anything that you'll probably have to install some extra packages to go with either Visual Studio Code or Visual Studio.

Comment: Actually, GTK3 was replaced with direct calls to libX11